# Where do I find the VMware Network Editor in VMware Player on Windows?

Tags: vmware-player

Starting with VMware Player 3.0, the installer does not create a shortcut to the Network editor anymore.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VMware Player 3.0 / 4.0:** [[Source]](http://www.eightforums.com/virtualization/5137-how-add-virtual-network-editor-vmware-player.html)

Manually extract the .exe out of the installer package.

- name-of-vmware-installer.exe /e .\extract
- In the extracted files, find network.cab
- Open or extract network.cab and copy vmnetcfg.exe into your VMware install directory.

**VMware Player 5.0:** [[Source]](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2155960)

Create a windows shortcut that runs with administrator privileges.  Set the following as the shortcut target:

> C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware
>   Player\vmnetui.dll" VMNetUI_ShowStandalone